# Transferring Joomla from local to remote host

Tags: joomla

I built a website on Joomla on a local host server and now I'm trying to upload it to the new hosting I bought.  So here it goes:

- I upload the Akeeba backup
- When I'm on the pre-installation page I click next then it asks me for > Connection information

I'm not sure what should I put there so I click next and it gives me this message:

> An error occurred while restoring the database. The error message can
>   be found below. Click on the × button at the top right of this dialog
>   message to close it and return to the database restoration page.
>   Access denied for user 'voiscypr_vacd'@'localhost' to database
>   'voiscypr_vacd' SQL=CREATE DATABASE `voiscypr_vacd` CHARACTER SET
>   `utf8`

Any ideas on how to fix it ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  This forum is really for programming questions, and your question isn't really about programming, but about installing / configuring your Joomla site.  You would have much greater luck, I think, posting to a different Stack Exchange based site dedicated to Joomla itself.  Here is a link, you can go there and sign up with the same ID (all the Stack Exchange sites share user credentials).  https://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should enter database connection information. You should create a new DB on your server and enter that DB name, DB username, and password when prompted.